# Time complexity for if and while loop m!=n

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement, while-loop, time-complexity

```
while (m != n) {
  if (m > n)
    m = m - n;
  else
    n = n - m;
}
```

the time complexity should be (m/n)-1 if (m>n) and (n/m)-1 if (n>m). Please tell me how it is O(n).
if I take m=32 and n=8:
Then it should be completed within 4 (=32/8) or so iterations. But its time complexity is shown as O(n).
i tried analyzing the problem but couldn't analyze it

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: O(n) is the *order* of time complexity, not the exact number of operations.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. And I recommend you read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: *"its time complexity is shown as O(n)."*: what is your source for this claim? Surely, `m` has an influence on the number of iterations. Try with `n=1, m=10000000`

Comment: The **n** in **O(n)** isn't the same as the `n` in your code. If you were using `a` and `b` the time complexity would be still be **O(n)** which means a linear relationship.

Comment: @WeatherVane "If you were using a and b the time complexity would be still be O(n) which means a linear relationship". This does not make sense - a linear relationship with what?. "n" must refer to a parameter in the code which theoretically can grow towards infinity, it is not just some name.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the OP implements the original version of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

The worst case complexity is linear in both parameters. To see this, consider `m` being 1 and `n` some arbitrary positive integer. In that case, `n-1` iterations must be performed subtracting 1 from `n` until `n` also becomes 1. Thus, in that case the complexity is `O(n)`. A symmetric case exists when `n=1` and `m` is arbitrary giving complexity `O(m)`.

Having arbitrary positive `n` and `m`, the number of iterations is in all cases less than `max(n,m)`. To see this, notice that after each iteration, `max(n,m)` is strictly less than before the iteration and the algorithm stops at the latest when `max(n,m)` is 1. Thus, at most `max(n,m)-1` iterations are needed.

Thus, the worst case complexity is `O(max(n,m))` and if it assumed that `n>m`, then this is equal to `O(n)`.

For completeness, it should be mentioned that when implemented with divisions, the complexity of the Euclidean algorithm is `O(log(min(n,m)))`.